# SSRS Grouping specific rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Wondering if it is possible to only group specific rows in a tablix as when I add a child group it groups all 3 row of my tablix and I need it to only group the bottom 2.

The tablix does not have a header and I need the top row to be grouped on 2 fields and the next 2 rows to be grouped with the above as well as several other fields

Am I just missing something completely obvious or can this just not be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cant be done like you descripe it. But you can use a workaround. You need to mark the rows you dont want to group with a indicator (this can be done in a calculated field) `Indicator = {0, 1}`. Then you group like you descriped it. The grouping should now look like this:

```
Value     Indicator
 1           0                '1st row of group
 12          1                '2nd row of group
 33          1                '3rd row of group
```

Now you add a filter to your tablix where you exclude all rows where the indicator value is `0`. Then it would look like this:

```
Value     Indicator
 12          1                '1st row of group
 33          1                '2nd row of group
```

Of course your indicator needs a expression which identifies the first row per group.

Comment: This points me in the right direction thanks, bit surprised there is no inbuilt functionality for this though and instead I must use a workaround